# Positioning of mesh with respect to it's parent

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a project in which I create 3d Widget to rotate, scale and translate a mesh.
I'm currently having some trouble with positioning the cone that I use for scaling the parent mesh.
This is my code:

```
function createScaleWidget(mesh, constScale){
    var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
    });
    var coneGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, constScale, 10, 50, 20, false);
    var cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeom,material);
    cone.position.y = bbox.max.y/2; //assuming all the objects are laid on the ground
    cone.position.z = bbox.max.z+10;
    cone.position.x = bbox.max.x+10;
    mesh.add(cone);
}
```

**mesh** is the mesh I'm creating the widget for,
**cone** is the widget.
I would like to have the cone in the middle of the mesh (with respect to y)
and in an angle with respect to the bounding box (the ideal would be to have it on the right of the face bounding box that is facing the camera).
Probably my problem is due to the fact that the **cone** is child of the **mesh** therefore the final position do not only depends on the bbox but also on the position of the **mesh** itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like that:

[image]

You are right you have to locate the cone relatively to its parent position, in this case - the mesh:

```
function createScaleWidget(mesh, constScale){
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
});
var coneGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, constScale, 10, 50, 20, false);
var cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeom,material);
cone.position.y = bbox.size().y / 2;
mesh.add(cone);
}
```

this worked for me while i did something similar. the cone should be placed next to one of the faces. to try another face you can then try:

```
cone.position.z = bbox.size().z / 2;
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked fine! Didn't know bboxes has the size() function

Comment: You are wellcome! and can approve my question if you like

Comment: Yep, sorry I'm kinda noob to stackoverflow :D